# Create time variable in perl

Tags: perl

I want to create a variable that will store hardcoded hours and minutes value. Rest stuff like min, day, date, year should be current date and time. How can I do this? I tried timelocal, localtime and many others, but they didn't work.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to expand on exactly what you're trying to accomplish. What are you trying to do? I would suggest looking at `Time::Piece` as a good module for manipulating time and date though.

Comment: As Sobrique says, [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) is likely to be a good fit. It overloads `localtime` so you can say just `my $now = localtime`, and `$now` becomes a `Time::Piece` object that you can manipulate and format as you wish. We can't help any more unless you say more about what you need to do.

Comment: Clarify what you're asking. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: How did `localtime` not work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you indeed use `localtime`, as in perldoc:
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html

```
($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);
```

Then, if you want to stick to using the broken-down components, you could overwrite whichever variables you want to "fix":

```
$hour = $my_hardcoded_hour;
$min  = $my_hardcoded_minute;
```

If instead you need to translate this back to "seconds since the epoch" (Jan 1, 1970, 12:00AM GMT) format, you need the `Time::Local` package:

http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html

```
use Time::Local;

$epoch_current_time_with_fixed_hour_min = 
    timelocal($sec, $my_hardcoded_minutes, $my_hardcoded_hour, $mday, $mon, $year);
```

Comment: This question and answer is quite the peanut gallery. Does anyone care to point out what's wrong, other than attempting to answer an underspecified question?

Comment: Thanks :)
It is exactly what I wanted. It served my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a complete date time object (like it seems according your description), use DateTime. Example:

```
use DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->now;  # initialize with current date time
$dt->set_hour(20);  #set your own hour
$dt->set_minute(20); #set your own minute
```